# Should I add a full stop/period at the end of each item in a bullet point list?

Tags: punctuation, lists, periods

Should I add a full stop/period at the end of each item in a bullet point list?

i.e.

- My first item.
- My second item.
- My third item.

or

- My first item
- My second item
- Or what about a longer item that might have other puncuation in it, like this. It doesn't seem right to miss the full stop/period off

Comment: This is a matter of local convention and personal taste. There is no overarching general rule in English orthography. If the publication you expect this to appear in mandates or recommends a style guide, use that. Otherwise if there's a convention evident in the works of other authors, follow that. Otherwise use your best judgement and taste.

Comment: Your point about the bullet point containing other punctuation is excellent, and has had me scratching my head in the past, as I hate adding periods after non-sentential points. I break the pseudo-rule 'always be consistent' (in spite of this being one of the best rules of thumb we have) on this one: periods discretionary. Of course, when the bullet points are quotes, it gets even messier.

Comment: This question has been asked, and answered, several times before. Please [search the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=period%20list%20item) before asking. It is also much faster than typing up an entire question. Thank you.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm battling with... I'm building a website, and I want it to be consistent across all pages. But some lists are short (one or two words), and others are longer sentences.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I don't see any of those search results mention my point about the longer item...